# Why the Enter key does not work with selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to create a form where pressing the enter key causes focus to go to the "next" form element on the page. That's my code, but it not working with "selectpicker" in bootstrap
HTML Code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 pdr0 ">
    <div class="col-md-12 pdl0 pdt5">DOB</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 pdl0 pdb0 pdt0">
        <asp:TextBox ID="DOB" runat="server" TabIndex="7" CssClass="TextBox validate[required] " />
        <span class="required"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 pdr0 ">
    <div class="col-md-12 pdl0 pdt5">Level</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 pdl0 pdb0 pdt0">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Level" TabIndex="8" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker  validate[required]" />
        <span class="required"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('body').on('keydown', 'input,button, a, select, textarea', function (e) {
    var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      focusable = form.find('input,button,a,select,textarea').filter(':visible:not([readonly]):enabled');
      next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) + 1);
      if (next.length) { next.focus(); } else { form.submit(); }
        return false;
      }
      else if (e.keyCode === 113) {
        $(".cmsbtupdate").click();
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you post html code?

Comment: try adding an event `change` with `keydown`

Comment: i have posted html code